# What's the difference between BackgroundImage and Image of a button?

Tags: winforms, image, button, background

I have a simple question, if I have a button called myButton in Windows Forms, what is the difference of myButton.Image and myButton.BackgroundImage?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`BackgroundImage` is like wallpaper, it covers the whole background.. you should use patterns or full pictures for the background. If you are just trying to show an icon use `Button.Image`

For the `Button.Image` property from MS documentation:

**The Image displayed on the button control.**

The BackgroundImage

**An Image that represents the image to display in the background of the control.**

So you can set a `BackgoundImage` as well as a `Button.Image` the `Button.Image` will be placed over top of the `BackgroundImage`

> Note: Images with translucent or transparent colors are not supported
>   by Windows Forms controls as background images. This property is not
>   supported on child controls whose RightToLeftLayout property is true.

Here is an example I just created of a `Button` with both `BackgroundImage` and `Button.Image` set. Clearly there is a background image, then my button text and a button image next to my text.

[image: BackGroundImage with Button.image]

The cool thing is you can change where you place your `Button.Image` with the `ImageAlign` property

[image: ImageAlign]

Here's the same button using an icon with transparency and NOT using RTL and I set the background color to light blue and it all works fine. So either my icon with transparency really isn't transparent or the docs are wrong.

[image]

Comment: So i may have a Button.Image with transparency?

Comment: Yes you can. Choose icons that have transparency for that.

Comment: I read the documentations, but for me the **"Image displayed on the button control."** and **An Image that represents the image to display in the background of the control.** have no difference in terms of language, so I wanted one example

Comment: I agree, just had that same discussion earlier today about how vague MS documentation is. I developed WinForms apps for years so I understand that difference from having worked with it. Hope that example helps you understand the difference

Comment: If i change the RightToLeftLayout property, I may have a background image with transparency?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example! This clarifies everything!

Comment: @CDSmith Does your transparency issue have anything to do with the `Form.TransparencyKey`? Also, it interesting to see that the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey(v=vs.110).aspx) state that property isn't supported when `RightToLeftLayout` is true.

Answer (score 2):

Background Image - The image as in the name suggests, gets set in the background and the text comes over it.

Image - The Image is adjacent(side-by side) to Text provided. (See in Image)

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "adjacent"?

Comment: As far as I can see, the myButton.BackgroundImage is not centered in the button, but the myButton.Image is, and they both behave the same with text...Am I missing something else?

Comment: My program dont have the behavior of your example...maybe my image is too big

Comment: In Background take big images. For Image take small ones.

Answer (score 0):

myButton.Image=>  The Image displayed on the button control.
myButton.BackgroundImage=> image to display in the background of the control.

Answer (score 0):

An advantage to BackgroundImage is the option of BackgroundImageLayout = Stretch/Zoom, which enables to adjust the icon image to the button size.